# Run .mcfunction every tick

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-behavior-packs

Is it possible in *Minecraft: Bedrock Edition* to have a `.mcfunction` execute every tick without a command block? I have the `.mcfunction` working but want to simplify and get rid of the command blocks totally. Also with command blocks, you have to waste one of your ticking areas to ensure it always works.

Comment: What do you mean by a function

Comment: @AwesomeT43 It's a part of Minecraft Bedrock behaviour packs.

Comment: yep. you can create custom function files which is just a list of commands in a file. You can execute the entire "function" by calling "/function functionname" in the minecraft console or you can put the same in a command block. But cant find anyway to execute it without the command block. Would like to have it called every tick. Its a pain to set up reusable mods like this since we cant package it easily. We have to tell anyone who wants to use the mod "ok first go set up a command block and add this command" - very manual and annoying.

Answer (score 2):

I had a hunt around on [bedrock.dev](https://wiki.bedrock.dev/) (check it out, might help you with future problems) and found this.

Functions that are listed in the file `BP/functions/tick.json`, where `BP` is your behaviour pack will be executed on every tick.

An example is below:

```
{
    "values": ["function_file_name_one", "function_file_name_two"]
}
```

Take a look at the [page](https://wiki.bedrock.dev/commands/mcfunction.html#running-functions-through-tick-json) I found for some more info and technical details.